# Entity Framework Core How To Solve ..Index 0-Error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am getting following error prompt from my Packet-Manager Console.

```bsh
PM> Update-Database -Context SQLiteTestDbContext
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.1.4 initialized 'SQLiteTestDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite' with options: None
System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

I don't know where the problem is. My connection string is stored in a `appsettings.json` in the project path.

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=_CHANGE_ME;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "SQLiteTestConnection": "Data Source=../DB-SQLite/Tests/TestDB.db"
  }
}
```

What is the problem there? The `Add-Migration` has worked for me but the next part with `Update-Database` won't work.

Comment: Add-Migration is not dependent on the connection string because it is autogenerated based on your context and models.  Update-Database, on the other hand is dependent on connection string.  "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."  is a connection string issue.  Can you post how you are obtaining and initializing the context with the connection string?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found my problem.
My connection string was not correct. Also I tried with the `ConfigurationManager` to get the *ConenctionString* which was stored in an `appsettings.json` but this won't work (its only for .config I guess).

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by editing `ConfigureService` Method in the `Startup` class.
the problem will be solved when you actually get connection string from Configuration property.
so the final shape of adding `dbContext` into Application Services in `ConfigureService` method should be like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<yourDBContext>(
        option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeConnection"))
    );
}
```